Does the 128-bit version of "Load SIMD&FP register #(immediate offset) `LDR` require FEAT_SVE or FEAT_FP, etc.?
I expect this instruction to load 128-bits from the address in x0 into the 128-bit register q0 as discussed here.
  ldr q0, [x0]

As you see in the first link, ARM calls this instruction "Load SIMD&FP Register (immediate offset)".
I am surprised they do not mention that it requires something like FEAT_FP or FEAT_AdvSIMD. Are the q registers always present in any ARMv8?

FEAT_FP and FEAT_AdvSIMD (they always go together) are meant to be near-universally supported on ARMv8-A.  The Architecture Reference Manual says that Arm will only license implementations which lack them in the case when they are "targeting specialized markets".  I agree that the manual is a bit vague on what exactly such an implementation does or doesn't have to support; perhaps they assume the implementer will tell you.

So in practice, when programming for generic ARMv8-A, you can assume that basic floating point and ASIMD, including the q/d/s/h/b/v register file and corresponding load/store instructions, are always present.  If you were programming for a specific stripped-down chip, you'd know about it.

If you step very carefully through the pseudocode for these instructions, there is a test to see whether it should trap as an invalid instruction.  Normally this is meant for the case where the functionality is present in hardware but disabled by the operating system or hypervisor, but you might find that this path would also be taken for an implementation which doesn't support it at all (e.g. perhaps the relevant bits of the relevant system registers would be hard-wired to values that lead to a trap).

Thank you @NateEldredge! What you say makes sense. I'm pretty sure the requirement is within CheckFPEnabled(), but I cannot easily track through that shared pseudocode. There's definitely no mention of those two features in the XML.
